# Default header in documentclass journal

Tags: header-footer, journal

I wish to submit an article to arXiv and am under the impression that if the formatting defined by `\documentclass{journal}` will do just fine. So my intention was to just accept whatever formatting was set up by default. Indeed it all looks  very good except for the header. The header appears to be a thin horizontal line at the top of the page (all fine) with the page number appearing above that line on the right (also fine) but on the left hand side just above the line there is what looks like a solitary comma which looks very odd. Is there some optional parameter that I should have passed to the journal class to specify what should go there?

Comment: looking at `texdoc paper` the `journal` class (which is just paper class with option `journal`) is intended for teh whole journal, inlcuding individual papers. for a single paper I think you are intended to use `paper` rather than `journal`

Comment: @David Carlisle: That's perfect - looks better now. If you put that as an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at

```
texdoc paper
```

the `journal` class (which is just `paper` class with option `journal`) is intended for the whole journal, including individual papers. for a single paper I think you are intended to use `paper` rather than `journal`.